# Pizza pie and doughnut with html

Tags: javascript, html, css, zurb-foundation

I have downloaded a project of pizza pie and doughnut graphs with html and etc from Zurb website.

For some reason when i open the HTML from my PC the graphs cant show up, only the title and basic information.

Is there anything missing? Do I need to download more stuff for support?

Here is the link for Zurb website where I have downloaded the project
https://zurb.com/playground/pizza-pie-charts

Comment: You'll need to show us the code you wrote to set it up. Edit your question with your code and point out the places you think are incorrect

Answer (score 0):

Look at their explanations.

You have to write the following in the head tag to make it works:
The first link is the CSS (cosmetics)
Then you have to download jquery (seems that library depend on jquery)
After that you have links for pizza.js

```
<link href="stylesheets/pizza.css" media="screen, projector, print" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/vendor/snap.svg.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.pizza.js"></script>
```

To test if it works, simply insert their code:

```
<ul data-pie-id="my-cool-chart">
  <li data-value="36">Pepperoni</li>
  <li data-value="14">Sausage</li>
  <li data-value="8">Cheese</li>
  <li data-value="11">Mushrooms</li>
  <li data-value="7">Chicken</li>
  <li data-value="24">Other</li>
</ul>

<script>Pizza.init();</script>
```

Replace it by the pie you ant to create

Comment: After trying to make it works, I had some issues. I take a look at tehir github repository and an issue is open on it.: https://github.com/zurb/pizza/issues/25

If I were you, I'll try to use another library for charts

Answer (score 0):

This Pie Graph Support it on Jquery 2.0

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.0.min.js"></script>
  <script src="dist/js/vendor/dependencies.js"></script>
  <script src="dist/js/pizza.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(window).load(function() {
      Pizza.init();
      $(document).foundation();
    });
  </script>
```

Replace This Line on the bottom of Code In side Body Tag